# Pipes between C# and Delphi, How to make it work?

Tags: c#, delphi, process, pipe

I have a console application (Host.exe) that is written in Delphi. It accepts stdin readln and responses to stdout by writeln.
Now, I want to use Host.exe in C# application in a way that C# gives input to Host.exe and gets the output from Host.exe
Ideally, I write the code below but it doesn't work: it hangs somewhere in the outputReader.ReadLine();

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(tmp, vbs);

Process pProcess = new Process();

pProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

//strCommand is path and file name of command to run
pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"Host.exe";
pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"runa " + tmp +"\"";
// runs script file tmp in background
pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

pProcess.Start();

StreamWriter inputWriter = pProcess.StandardInput;
StreamReader outputReader = pProcess.StandardOutput;

while (true)
{
    inputWriter.WriteLine("getmsg");
    inputWriter.Flush();
    string s = outputReader.ReadLine(); // then do something with it

    inputWriter.WriteLine("progressglobal");
    inputWriter.Flush();

    string p = outputReader.ReadLine();
    if (p == "100")
    {
        break;
    }
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
inputWriter.WriteLine("exit");
inputWriter.Flush();                    
pProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Many thanks for any suggestions in advance !

Comment: Does your Delphi application return a string with a new line symbol? If not, you application is waiting forever. Or maybe you should debug the Delphi app, what does is it do when the request comes in?

Comment: Is this a text encoding issue? Are you writing UTF-16 in C#, but expecting ANSI on the other side of the pipe?

Comment: Yes, my Delphi application uses writeln to output string with new line every time...

Comment: not sure how to change encoding issue in C# and Delphi?

Comment: The Delphi code uses ANSI almost certainly. That's what Writeln and Readln in Delphi do, even in Unicode enabled Delphi. What did you see when you ran the Delphi app under the debugger?

Comment: It is very strange that the Delphi app does not stop when debugging,, anyway, I've made this work by only reading output from Host.exe (One-way interaction only), this case solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You read the line twice:

`string s = outputReader.ReadLine();`

and

`string p = outputReader.ReadLine();`

It seems you only need the last line as the variable `s` is not used.

Comment: Ideally, C# sends two commands "getmsg" and "progresslocal", to Host.exe, and the Delphi returns two lines of string...